# Minimum openGL initializations

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to learn OpenGL and currently trying to use it with Qt. The thing I am trying to do is to load frames from a video file into a texture and then display it on the screen. The only thing I might try and do later is to enable zoom functionality on this. Keeping that in mind, what is the minimum OpenGL initializations that I need to use to maximize performance. More specifically, do I need to diasable certain features, so that I can maximize performance for my very limited needs at the moment.

For example, the Qt tutorial on OpenGL initializes it as:

```
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
 glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
 glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
 glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
 glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
 static GLfloat lightPosition[4] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
```

I think I should safely be able to disable most of these but am not sure as I am still trying to figure out what most of these things will actually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Enables depth testing which prevents triangles from overwriting others when they should be hidden behind others. Leave enabled to avoid the artifacts.

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Prevents triangles from being drawn when they are facing away from you. Leave enabled for better performance.

```
 glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
 glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
 glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
 static GLfloat lightPosition[4] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
```

All these are part of the deprecated fixed function pipeline and can be removed and emulated with shaders.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just starting to learn, here's additional info:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```

Leave it only if you're planning to draw 3D shapes

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
```

Remove it until you get used to the concept of clockwise, and counter-clockwise importance of drawing the points. otherwise you might fail to see your first rendered shapes, because they could be culled. First draw them without this, then enable it and experiment with clockwise and counter-clockwise drawing.

```
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
```

Leave that. It simply instructs the renderer to mix different colors and smooth them along the shapes. If you put different colors to different points, they'll get interpolated smoothly.

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
static GLfloat lightPosition[4] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);
```

If you're past the point of rendering simple shapes, use these to experiment with lighting. You should also provide normals to your geometry, in order to see the effects. If you're really in the beginning, comment those out until you're more familiar with drawing shapes.

Good luck!